# can the require user's permission be set in a gpo?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, remote-desktop

We are using Windows 2008R2 Server for our Domain Controller and a Windows 2008 for our Remote Desktop users.

We have to support them or get them out of something on a regular basis. We have quite a few users. I checked the group policy but I couldn't find it but that doesn't mean it does not exist.

Can the Require user's permission, as shown below, be set in the group policy or does it have to be set on each user?  If so, where do I change it?

[image]

If not, is there an easy way to change this on all users so I don't have to manually do it for our large number of users?

Comment: Also can be done per Terminal Server: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771538.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Q: "Can it be set in Group Policy?". A: "Yes it can."

Go to Computer Configuration>Policies>Administrative Templates>Windows Components>Remote Desktop Services>Remote Desktop Session Host>Connections

Specifically the `Set rules for remote control of Remote Desktop Services user sessions` and change it to `Enabled` and set the option to `Full Control with User's Permission`

**EDIT:**

You can also se it under User Configuration. If you set it under Computer Configuration it will apply to all users logging onto the server where that GPO is applied. If you set it under User Configuration it will apply to all users that the GPO applies to. If you set it under both Computer Configuration and User Configuration then the Computer Configuration setting takes precedence.

Thanks to TheCleaner for the assist in adding the additional detail for the actual setting.

Comment: Glad to help. See my edit.